# Temporarily group files in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have quite a few projects and sometimes I work with files from different projects that I would like to group temporarily. I want to be able to mark a few files and tell them to jump into a temporary folder, but without being moved from their original places. Kinda like the "Scope to This", but for files that are located in different places. When I delete the temp folder it shouldn't delete the files from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Favorite Documents](https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension (developed by me) you can add such files to a favorites folder for quick access.

Comment: Played around with it for only five minutes and I love it. It's an awesome plugin, good work Sergey!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be solved by tagging?
Check out [VsTagExplorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb6c23f1-6f5b-42f6-bdd8-8536338aadbc) (not mine)

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for. But it doesn't seem to be installable with VS 2013. Outdated perhaps?